# Display ManyToManyField Results of a Query Set

Tags: python, django

My app (samples) utilizes an html form to get user input. I then use this input to search for matches in a database table. I would then like to print the results for every row in the matching database column.

Models.py

```
...

class Method(models.Model):
    method_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    method_description = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self): #python 3.3 __str__
        return self.method_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['method_name']

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(Contact)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['project_name']




class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField()      
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    method = models.ForeignKey(Method)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sample_ID

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sample_ID']
```

views.py

```
def sample_lookup(request):
    form = SampleLookupForm(request.POST or None)
    id = ''
    results = []
    errors = False
    catresults = ()
    categories = ['Sample Name', 'Date', 'Project', 'Method']

    if form.is_valid():
        id = form.cleaned_data['Sample_ID'].upper()
        # Iterate through all sample IDs and check.
        # Not efficient for large query sets. 
        for s in Sample.objects.all():
            if s.sample_ID == id:
                results = [s.sample_name, s.extraction_date, s.project, s.method]
                catresults = zip(categories, results)
                errors = False
                break
        if not results:
            errors = True
    context = {
    "errors": errors, "catresults": catresults,
    "q": id, "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'sample_lookup.html', context)
```

(I know this view is horribly ugly but it works for now.)

After this, I print it out in html using

```
{% for result in catresults %}
<!-- Field = result.0, value = result.1 -->
```

The query itself is the sample ID. I search all columns of Sample for a matching ID. When/if there is a match, I print every field of that column. For the CharField, DateField, and ForeignKey field, I get a nice string that matches the information for that sample.

However, for the ManyToManyField, i get samples.Project.None.

```
Field         Value
Sample_Name   Sample_A
Date          2.2.15
Project       samples.Project.None
Method        A real method
```

So it appears that s.project gives samples.Project.None. I have a feeling this is due to the fact that this is a ManyToMany field. How can I get all the results from this field?

I tried s.project.project_name, and that didn't work.

django = 1.8
python = 2.7

Thank you

Comment: That's a M2M, if you do: `s.project.all()` which returns a queryset, and then oterate over it, you will get the sting name.

Comment: That worked perfectly and in hindsight seems obvious. Thank you!